# Import Error: No module named arch

Tags: python, ipython, arch

I am facing this error in iPython notebook even after installing running pip install arch command and successfully installing it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did your ipython version is comparable with your pip version? Maybe you start ipython with version 3 but install `arch` with version 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the Kernel

To isolate the problem, try importing it in a normal python environment you start in the command line.