# Why I cannot import arch module in python despite it showing in my pip list?

Tags: python, pip, arch

**pip list** shows:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
absl-py                0.9.0
arch                   4.15
async-generator        1.10
attrs                  19.3.0
auquan-toolbox         2.1.92
backcall               0.1.0
.....
```

But when I use from arch `import arch_model`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-f7e7e7ccf968> in <module>
----> 1 from arch import arch_model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arch'
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Just a suggestion -> always check if your question was already asked on StackOverflow. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542243/import-error-no-module-named-arch

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Python3 or Python2?
You have to use Python3 with pip3 according to the github documentation https://github.com/bashtage/arch: *arch is Python 3 only. Version 4.8 is the final version that supported Python 2.7.*

With Python3 and pip3 I get it to work:

arch 4.15 ($ pip3 list | grep arch)
This works:

```
import arch
```

But i think you want that command:

```
from arch import arch_model
```

Both are successfull.

(Python 3.8.2 with pip3)